# How to solve a differential equation using NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a question, I would appreciate it, if you could help me.

Can I solve following differential equation using the `NDSolve`?

```
 (d/dx)[( a + 2 b cs Cosh(f(x)) E^(1/2  b  f'(x) ) ) f'(x)]  = 
     E^(1/2 b f'(x)) a Sinh(f(x))
```

With following Boundary condition:

```
a + 2 b cs Cosh(f(0)) E^(1/2  b  f'(0) )= er
```

and

```
f'(0.3)=0
```

Where a, b, er are aribitary positve real numbers.
The range of `a, b, er` and `cs` is between `0.1` up to `0.5`.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `NDSolve` works only with particular numeric parameters, not with arbitrary symbolic ones.  Perhaps `ParametricNDSolve`?

Comment: @ MMM sorry, at x=0

Comment: @MMM Yes it is.

Comment: @MMM f'(R=0.3)=0, so {x,0,0.3}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a start.

```
eq = D[(a + 2*b*cs*Cosh[f[x]]* Exp[1/2 b f'[x]])*f'[x], x] ==
     Exp[1/2* b*f'[x]]*a*Sinh[f[x]];

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, a + 2*b*cs*Cosh[f[0]] E^(1/2*b*f'[0]) == er, f'[0.3] == 
     0}, f[x], {x, 0, 0.3}, {a, b, cs, er}];

Plot[sol[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], {x, 0, 0.3}]
```

[image]

Comment: @aminbk are you still waiting for an answer?

Comment: no. I got my answer.